# FTP polling in OSB

Tags: oracle, osb

I've created a ftp server on localhost:21

I created on OSB (I use OEPE to play with OSB) the proxy service called FTPpol
I configured FTPpol in this way:

General configuration(first tab): messaging service

Message Type Configuration: text in message requeste type and i leave the message response type on None

Transport Configuration: protocol: ftp and Endpoint Uri: ftp://127.0.0.1/

FTP Transport Configuration: User Authentication: External User and i use a service account previously created (with the username and password need to access to ftp)

After this configuration I receive a connection error on the console everytime the proxy try the polling. The username and password are correct and the server ftp is up and reachable.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use an adapter for it, as seem here:

https://blogs.oracle.com/MarkSmith/entry/osb_and_ftp_adapter_in_11g